# Как вывести username из таблицы users по id в сессии?

Tags: php, mysqli, регистрация

Есть таблица users. В ней есть username и id столбцы. Собственно, нужно вывести username на страницу сайта, чтобы авторизированный пользователь его видел. Как это сделать на php7+MySQLi?
Я наговнокодил так:

```
$res=mysqli_query($success, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Id=".$_SESSION['id']);
$userRow=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
```

И справедливо получаю ошибки:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: success in D:\www\site.local\index.php on line 14
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in D:\www\site.local\index.php on line 14
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in D:\www\site.local\index.php on line 15
```

Comment: а документацию к `mysqli::query` читать пробовали?

Comment: Надо бы почитать... А вы знаете в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: в `myqli_query`. Что такое `$success` по вашему?!

Comment: Без него тоже не работает.

Comment: Ну там же английским языком сказано: `$success` не объявлена нигде. И вообще странное название для переменной, в которой должен быть коннект к БД

Comment: Коннект к БД в самом начале страницы. Без нее выдает другие ошибки, а именно

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in D:\www\site.local\index.php on line 14

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in D:\www\site.local\index.php on line 15

Comment: Я рад, что у вас в начале страницы есть коннект в БД, но как у вас называется переменная, которая этот самый коннект собой представляет ?

Comment: $connection! Все заработало!

Comment: Спасибо, я просто новичек и вот у меня глупые ошибки :)